# #if - #else - #endif breaking F# Script

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting, f#-4.0

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and `fsi.exe` from F# v4.0 I' trying to run this script:

```
//error.fsx

#if INTERACTIVE
    let msg = "Interactive"
#else
    let msg = "Not Interactive"
#endif

let add x y =
    x + y

printfn "%d" (add 1 2)
```

*Output:* **error.fsx(12,15): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'add' is not defined**

If I then comment out the `#if`-`#else`-`#endif` block, it works fine:

```
// fixed.fsx

//#if INTERACTIVE
//    let msg = "Interactive"
//#else
//    let msg = "Not Interactive"
//#endif

let add x y =
    x + y

printfn "%d" (add 1 2)
```

*Output:* **3**

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong (rather than this being a bug) but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the indentation of `let msg`. The following works fine:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
let msg = "Interactive"
#else
let msg = "Not Interactive"
#endif

let add x y =
    x + y

printfn "%d" (add 1 2)
```

I do have to say, I'm not entirely sure why the code gives exactly the error message you mention - I suspect this is a bug in the error reporting and it wold be worth [reporting it to the F# team](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp). At the very least, there should be a sensible error message!

It seems that with the indentation, the F# parser actually parses the code as follows:

```
let msg = "Interactive"
let add x y =
  x + y 
    printfn "%d" (add 1 2)
```

The spacing before `let msg` causes the compiler to treat `printfn` as being indented too. You can see that this is the case if you look at the type of the `y` variable in your editor using a tool tip...

Comment: Thanks Tomas! As soon as you pointed that out it made sense.  I grabbed the example code from [here](http://brandewinder.com/2016/02/06/10-fsharp-scripting-tips/) (#3) and just assumed that it would work as it. Thanks much!

Comment: It is a funny error - I spent a bit more time to figure out what's going on and I think this is a bug (in error reporting, at least).

Comment: Matt Klein: sorry about that! I'll fix the post, possibly some formatting got mangled there.

Comment: Woah, you're fast Mathias! I just finished created a Disqus account so I could let you know directly on your blog!

Comment: Thanks again @TomasPetricek ! I've submitted this issue to the F# team [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1564).